# ie6 png transparent not working

Tags: internet-explorer-6

```
<img src="/images/home-1a.png" id ="tab66"  alt="home" />

#tab66 {
 margin-left:0px;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(...);
}
```

This is my code of png image in ie6 but still it does not show transparency

Comment: One of the reasons why IE6 must die. There are several [fixes](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/png-transparency-in-ie6/) for it.

Comment: tried all fixes but don't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jQuery plugin:
http://allinthehead.com/retro/338/supersleight-jquery-plugin

That said you should avoid having to use this hack in the first place.
Use .GIF's unless you *really* have to use PNG

Answer (score 1):

```
body{ background: #0D657B;}
.png_hack {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  background-image: url(Img/png.png) !important;
  background-image: none;
  filter: none !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='Img/png.png');
}
```

it's works
http://www.newstyleonline.net/post/ie6-png-hack.html

Answer (score 0):

That is because `AlphaImageLoader` works like `background-image`, showing *behind* the image inside the img tag - the most common trick here is replacing `src="/images/home-1a.png"` with a 1x1 pixels transparent gif.

A quicker solution for you here would be:

```
<div id="tab66"></div>

#tab66 {
 margin-left:0px;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(...);
 width: Xpx;
 height: Ypx;
}
```

if you want to automate this, I'd recommend instead [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/).